# "ich" in different cases

Tags: grammar

So how do you say "ich" in different cases?
Is there any helping method like helping questions or something for each case?

1. nominative: ich
2. genitive: ?
3. dative: ?
4. accusative: ?

Also, I think I heard that all German words are either male, female or neuter gender, so what about word ich? You get der, das, die or none for ich?

Answer (score 2):

There are many sources on the Internet that already answer that question. For example, you could take a look at [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ich).

```
Case | Singular | Plural
Nom  | ich      | wir
Gen  | meiner   | unser
Dat  | mir      | uns
Acc  | mich     | uns
```

*Ich*, as a pronoun, does not have an article. *Ich* simply represents you yourself as *I* does in English. Also, your own biological gender does not matter then.
It is worth noting that there's also a substantive "*das Ich*", meaning *das Selbst* (self) or *der Ego* (ego), which is neuter.

Your statement that all German words have a grammatical gender is wrong inasmuch it should read "all German nouns".

Comment: *Ich* does have a gender: it's just not visible, because there is no article. But you can see it in *ich bin die/der/das Schönste*, right?

Comment: @Cerberus I disagree. The article "der/die/das" is associated with the substantive "Schönste". Compare: "(Die) Heidi[=Sie] ist die Schönste". "Sie" is just the replacement for the name (including a potential article). If the article would be applied to the pronoun, it would precede it immediately: *"Die sie ist die Schönste" (which is obviously wrong). Furthermore, where would the article be if there's no further substantive but an adjective?

Comment: The article does not directly modify the subject; it modifies *Schönste*. However, it could be argued that *die/der/das Schönste* modifies the subject, *ich*. It must be of the same gender as *ich* and changes accordingly as *ich* is a male or a female speaker. *Die Königin is die Schönste* is similar. Unless it is possible to say *das kleine Mädchen ist die Schönste*; is that possible?

Comment: @Cerberus I wouldn't say that it 'modifies' the subject. If you use "sein", it simply means equality "Ich = der Schönste". I also don't think it has to be the same gender: "Du bist das Beste, was mir je passiert ist", but also "Du bist der/die Beste". Furthermore, when you speak to a child, you can apply both "das" for "das Kind" or "der" or "die" for its actual gender: "Du bist der dümmste Junge/das dümmste Mädchen/das dümmste Kind" - "Du bist der/die dümmste von allen". In your last sentence you should, technically speaking, use "das"; but "die" is fine. – Anyway. "Ich" has no article.

Comment: Hmm I would say you *can* change genders mid-sentence with a copula, then, but the subject still has an invisible gender in those sentence. I conclude that based on your *in your last sentence you should, technically speaking, use "das"*.

Answer (score 0):

First-person singular pronoun:

1. nominative: ich
2. genitive: meiner
3. dative: mir
4. accusative: mich

It is only nouns and certain pronouns that have grammatical gender, not for example verbs.  The word "ich" is genderless.  The possessive pronoun "mein" is inflected according to case and gender in the same manner as the indefinite article (ein).